# SOM U-Matrix generation

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, som

I have been searching online and trying to understand the literature I have, but something is eluding me.

Given a SOM, when visualized with a U-Matrix, does the U-Matrix represent the distance between a given node and every other node, or the distance between a node and its direct neighbours?

Regards,
Jack Hunt

EDIT:- Suggestions for alternative visualization techniques are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the color of a node in the U-matrix is based on the distance between neighboring nodes in the lattice ([link](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/jhollmen/dippa/node24.html)). There are other ways to color a U-matrix, but that is the most common.

Other visualization techniques depend entirely upon your data and what you are looking for.